# Can I temporarily ignore preloaded HSTS on Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: https, google-chrome-devtools, hsts

As a Developer/Security researcher I want to ignore **preloaded HSTS** in Google Chrome (and  Firefox / Edge) in some special cases. `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` does NOT allow to remove preloaded HSTS entries. Also I don't want to remove them permanently. Best would be something like a Checkbox in Devtools that can just disable HSTS temporarily while Devtools are open. Is there any way?

Comment: That is the obvious page where such an option would appear, if it existed, so I doubt it exists. I suspect that building Chromium from source is in your future, where you can freely edit the preload list as required.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it could (and should) also be in DevTools. The internals/settings is not the right place for a developer to override settings for testing - I think it should be in DevTools. But I couldn't find anything...